# How to Update/Edit Database Field with Using Entity Framework and Mapper

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework-4, automapper

This is a specific question. We are coding a wcf service with using C#, EF4.1 and Mapper.
We don't want to use stored procedures... Anyway; Problem is, we want to edit address field on db. But we can't save edited address to db.

```
    public int EditAddress(int userId, Address address)
    {
        using(var mobileServiceContext = new MobileServiceContext())
        {
            Address oldAddress = mobileServiceContext.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(p => p.UserId == userId && p.AddressId == address.AddressId);
            Address lastAddress = Mapper.Map(address, oldAddress);

            //save new-last address with ? HOW ?
            //mobileServiceContext.Addresses.Attach(updatedAddress); //doesn't work
            mobileServiceContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        return address.AddressId;
    }
```

Here is our edited function;

```
    public int EditAddress(int userId, Address address)
    {
        using(var mobileServiceContext = new MobileServiceContext())
        {
            Address oldAddress = mobileServiceContext.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(p => p.UserId == userId && p.AddressId == address.AddressId);
            Address lastAddress = Mapper.Map(address, oldAddress);

            mobileServiceContext.Addresses.Attach(lastAddress); //error on this line
            mobileServiceContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(lastAddress, EntityState.Modified);
            mobileServiceContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        return address.AddressId;
    }
```

A note: "Address address" class already has address.Id field.

It's very complicated design that we made in here, also it's hard to read for reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using AutoMapper in this scenario, you can do the following:

```
//this assumes that the AddressId in address is exists in the database: just attach it to the addresses set
mobileServiceContext.Addresses.Attach(address);
//this tells ef that the object is in a modified state
mobileServiceContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(address, entityState.Modified);
//savechanges will now update the database
mobileServiceContext.SaveChanges();
```

I don't see a need for AutoMapper or any mapping utility here since we're not mapping a data model to a view model (or doing anything along those lines).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It worked one-time. When we try to work it second time; we are getting this error; ( on ...Addresses.Attach(address); )"An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key." And there is no helpfull information in inner-exception

Comment: @LostInLib - No problem :) Sorry I only read the first part of the comment.

Comment: Are you trying to attach the same object twice to the same context (in one call, that is)?

Comment: I updated my question. We didn't attach same object / we didn't use Attach or other method to edit object... I also, try to disable mapper //Address lastAddress = Mapper.Map(address, oldAddress); but no luck... Anyway, thank you very much. Your answer was right, and it can work on clean code. ( Our EditAddress method went ~30 methods before to get here =) )